# Just Give me Ububtu and the latest or version that works the best ? Please

Tags: downloads

OK, so I originally downloaded Ubuntu from the Ubuntu.com website, just about one month ago, and how I got it, I damn sure dont know, but I got 12.0, and have had nothing but problems since. Not knowing anything about Ubuntu other than its an operating system, and I need one. I was using windows 7 unreg. copy, so I elected to just wipe it out and out only ubuntu on my hard drive, looking back now, I wish I could have figured out how to put both on the hard drive, I would have. But, anyway, heres my question.....If I wanted to and I do, start over, my goal is to just have a operating system that works and works well without to much B.S., Im not a computer nerd, and not looking at becoming one anytime soon, So what is the best And Easiest way to get rid of 12.0 and get whatever version of Ubuntu that is best for me and easiest to do, Please help, my computer is pretty much useless now, so a solution to this problem would like make my day.  Thank You

Comment: What does "the best OS version" mean? I think it means the best OS for your computer's hardware and for your use case. Your use case is as a replacement for Windows 7, but you haven't provided any information about your hardware.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you want 32 or 64 bit but, as you had Windows 7 installed, I'm going to guess that you have a 64 bit CPU. If you don't then download the 32 bit version.

Anyhow, it is my experience that the most universally working versions of the Ubuntu family is those in the LTS (Long Term Stable) builds. Those are supported for a long time and you needn't worry much about the OS - you just use it. It works out well. On the other hand, you don't have to 'just use it' but you can actually make it do what you want it to do.

As you're coming from the Windows family and want simplicity, I'm going to go ahead and recommend [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/). The LXDE is light, familiar, and easy to work with. The WM (Window Manager - not to be mistaken for "Windows" the OS) is also easy enough - no real needs to configure. It *just works* for the most part.

Having said that, I'd suggest Lubuntu which you can download [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu/LTS). You'll want the Standard PC version and *probably* the 64 bit version. (64 bit means you can throw longer instruction sets at the CPU but that's immaterial at this point. Your CPU *probably* supports it if it's from within the last 10 years or so.)

Anyhow, head there and download the .ISO. You can burn the ISO to disk (as an image, not a direct copy) or you can use a tool like unetbootin to 'burn' it to a Live USB (format the USB with FAT32). Either way works. Boot to the Live disk environment and then see if it works for you. If it does, follow the installation instructions - just click the icon and go through it, it's pretty simple.

If you need help installing then ask a **new** , specific, question or use the online resources.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to be a computer nerd to understand and use the system successfully and nobody expects you to, but it would surely help you, if you would accept that an operating system change might take a little learning and not blame and curse the system for everything that does not work right away. Especially considering that you probably want help and not only tell us how much you think the system sucks.

Having said that, I know how much issues can be frustrating, so why don't you start by editing your question and specifying exactly what you had problems with? Is it graphics, sound, games, programs, media playback, network? So far I know nothing about your issues with the system, just that there apparently were problems.

Generally, Ubuntu 12.04 (I guess that is the version you're referring to, since there is no 12.0) is a rather stable release, at least I have had the least trouble with it.

It also depends on the hardware that is used, maybe you care to share that as well?